# Getting data from spawn process in Node.js from a Python script

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, child-process

I am running a Python script from a Node.js app using import instead of require, with the following code:

```js
import { spawn } from "child_process";
  async foo(): Promise<fooResponse> {
    try {
      let dataToSend: string = "";
      const pythonProcess = spawn('python', [__dirname + "\\script.py"],{cwd:__dirname});
      pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        dataToSend = data.toString();
      });
      return {
        message: dataToSend,
      };
    } catch (e) {
      if (e instanceof Error) {
        return {
          message: "Error",
        };
      }
      return {
        message: "Error",
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Inside my *script.py* I have this:

```py
print('Hello from python')
```

I need that `foo` returns the `'Hello from python'` that is returned from the Python script. As you can see I tried with the variable `dataToSend` but when I return it, it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import the `once` function from events

```js
import { once } from 'events'
```

then replace the `.on` line with the following:

```js
dataToSend = (await once(pythonProcess.stdout, 'data')).toString()
```